# Who is the person Kreese called at the end of S03E10?

Tags: character, cobra-kai

My GF insists it's the Sensei guy who sabotaged Daniel in Karate Kid 3.  Clearly it's a person from Kreese's past, and the show doesn't have a problem bringing back any character from the KK universe.  Does anyone know who that guy is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe or maybe not

As per Jon Hurwitz and Hayden Schlossberg  from [TVline](https://tvline.com/2021/01/03/cobra-kai-finale-recap-season-3-episode-10-december-19/)

> **TVLINE**: At the end of the finale, Kreese reached out to his old army buddy Terry for help. Has that role been cast yet and, if so, who will be playing him?
>
> **Jon Hurwitz** : Just because Kreese reached out to somebody, doesn’t necessarily mean that he’s returning to the show. That said, on our show, we try to bring back the original actor who played characters in the past as much as possible. We all loved the character of Terry Silver in The Karate Kid 3 and his portrayal by Thomas Ian Griffith, so if that character was to return for Season 4, we’d hope that he’d be the one playing him.
>
> **Hayden Schlossberg**: There’s no confirmation, anything can happen, really. But I will say: If you do love Terry Silver, this is probably the best show to tune into to see if he does show up. [Laughs] But we can’t promise anything at this point because it’s all a mystery.